# I Really Want To Go Here!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My Prefix is a very strong animal
>
> Be careful not to get killed
>
> My Infix can be considered as a luxurious vehicle
>
> That everyone must want to have
>
> My suffix is a really famous company
>
> There is even a museum made just for it

Note :

> The title is also a hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Random guess

> Oxford

My Prefix is a very strong animal

> Strong as an ox.

Be careful not to get killed

> They can get angry.

My Infix can be considered as a luxurious vehicle

> There's a luxury car called Jaguar XF (Thanks Sedrick :D)

That everyone must want to have

> Yeah.

My suffix is a really famous company

> Ford is a popular car company.

There is even a museum made just for it

> [Right here!](https://www.thehenryford.org/)

Title

> People want to go to university at Oxford.

Comment: Correct answer but u haven't answered the museum part. Will give checkmark after that.

Comment: Done :D @KevinL

Comment: Your infix is not what I meant. Try to find the right one :D

Comment: Okay will do :D

Comment: Maybe it's this. ROT13( Gurer'f n yhkhel pne pnyyrq Wnthne KS)

Comment: Yep that's correct @sedrick

Comment: Will accept ur answer tomorrow okay? @QuantumTwinkie

Comment: Sound great @KevinL :D Great puzzle